# Jaudiotagger change tags only after reboot device

Tags: java, android, jaudiotagger

I have this code:

```
 File mp3 = new File(song.getPath());
 AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(mp3);
 Tag tag = f.getTag();
 tag.setField(FieldKey.TITLE,songTitle.getText().toString());
 tag.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM,albumTitle.getText().toString());
 tag.setField(FieldKey.ARTIST,artistTitle.getText().toString());
 AudioFileIO.write(f);
```

Changes will take effect only after restart device. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The problem is with Android rather than jaudiotagger since clearly the files have been saved BEFORE device reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a broadcast to media scanner then refresh content resolver to be able to see changes of mp3 file.

`sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(mp3)));`